# Moving Azure Key Vault from one tenant to another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Moving Azure key vault between subscriptions of the same tenant is possible Microsoft azure. But how can I move the key vault from tenant A to tenant B in Microsoft Azure.

Comment: I think you should contact Azure support in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Moving resources across tenant is not supported.** For a cross subscription move, the target subscription must exist in an enabled state within the same tenant as the source subscription.

You could refer to this [Checklist before moving resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#checklist-before-moving-resources).

> The source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same
>   Active Directory tenant.